# Is there an NPM location where I can download Gulp 4 or a pre-release of Gulp 4?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm using a package.son where I list all the Gulp NPM modules. In that file I have "gulp": "3.8.11",

I would like to use Gulp4 and I read here some different ways to access it:

```
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429727/how-do-i-install-gulp-4
```

But is it possible to also do this with a package.json? When I try to look at versions of "gulp" the auto part of Visual Studio doesn't prompt me for anything more than a 3.9 version.

Also is there a way that I could have some tasks use Gulp3 and others uses Gulp4?

Comment: Why the vote to close this question?

Comment: Why would you want some tasks to use gulp3?

Comment: @SteveLacy - I though that changes were needed to the tasks to run with Gulp4 so while moving from 3 to 4 then I was thinking it would be a good idea to be able to use both at once.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate, but regardless:

```
npm install gulpjs/gulp#4.0 --save-dev
```

That adds this to the package.json:

```
"gulp": "gulpjs/gulp#4.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the only solution that I could get to work:

```
"gulp-4.0.build": "4.0.0-build.a271520",
```

Note that the version details on the right were added automatically by Visual Studio.