# Why does vinyl.isVinyl() return false for vinyl files emitted by gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, through2, gulp-plugin

I am learning about the gulp source code and tried to write a gulp plugin.

Now I am confused about something.

This is my plugin code below:

```
module.exports = function(){
    return through2.obj(function(file,encode,callback){
        console.log(vinyl.isVinyl(file));//false
        console.log(file._isVinyl) // undefined

        // the reason ? file is not Object of vinyl ? file's property of '_isVinyl' is undefine ?

        if(file.isNull()){
            callback(null,file);
        }
        if(file.isStream()){
            file.contents = file.contents.pipe(through2(function(chuck,encode,callback){
                if(util.isNull(chuck)){
                    callback(null, chuck);
                }
                if(util.isBuffer(chuck)){
                    chuck = new Buffer(String(chuck)
                        .replace(commentReg, '')
                        .replace(blankSpaceReg,''))
                }
                callback(null,chuck);
            }));
        }
        if(file.isBuffer()){
            file.contents = new Buffer(String(file.contents)
                .replace(commentReg, '')
                .replace(blankSpaceReg,''));
        }
        callback(null,file);
    })
}
```

This is the part of the gulp source code where [`vinyl`](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl) files are created:

[`https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs/blob/master/lib/src/wrap-with-vinyl-file.js`](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs/blob/master/lib/src/wrap-with-vinyl-file.js)

**MY CONFUSION:**

The [`transformFunction`](https://github.com/rvagg/through2#transformfunction) registered with `though2.obj()` receives a `file` object that should be a `vinyl` file.

Why does `vinyl.isVinyl()` return `false`?

Why doesn't the `file` object have a `_isVinyl` property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a matter of which versions of `vinyl-fs` and `vinyl` you look at on Github and which versions of `vinyl-fs` and `vinyl` your local `gulp` installation is using.

You probably installed gulp from [`npmjs.com`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp) by typing:

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp
```

This currently installs version `3.9.1` of gulp. You can see which versions of `vinyl-fs` and `vinyl` the `3.9.1` version of gulp depends on by using [`npm ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls). Here's the (abbreviated) output from that command:

```
└─┬ gulp@3.9.1
  └─┬ vinyl-fs@0.3.14
    └─┬ vinyl@0.4.6
```

So `gulp@3.9.1` depends on `vinyl-fs@0.3.14` and `vinyl-fs@0.3.14` depends on `vinyl@0.4.6`.

Here are links to those version on GitHub:

https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs/tree/v0.3.14 
https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl/tree/v0.4.6

As you can see on GitHub `vinyl@0.4.6` does **not** have a `._isVinyl` property. Only newer versions like `vinyl@1.2.0` [have this property](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl/blob/v1.2.0/index.js#L36).

Since `gulp@3.9.1` emits vinyl files using `vinyl@0.4.6` the vinyl files emitted by your gulp installation don't have the `._isVinyl` property. And that's why the `vinyl.isVinyl()` function returns `false` in your example.

The current [development version for the upcoming gulp 4.0](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/4.0) uses `vinyl@1.2.0` . If you were to [install that version of gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34267286/5892036) the `vinyl.isVinyl()` call in your example would return `true`.